# Factory Boy populating Local DB instead of Test DB

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, factory-boy

I set up ~100 unit test for a django app, and later realized each unit test run was creating test users in my local database, instead of the test database. Any idea why?

***apps/user/tests/factories.py***

```
class CompanyFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = Company

    title = fake.name()


class UserFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = User

    auth0_id = fake.random_number()
    email = "unit_test_user@cart.com"
    company = SubFactory(CompanyFactory)
```

When running a test that uses the factory like this, fake users are being persisted in the local DB:

[image: Djano Admin after test runs]

Anyone know why this behavior might be happening?

Here's what my database looks like in local settings:

```
DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2",
        "NAME": "mia",
        "USER": "mia_dev",
        "PASSWORD": "test123",
        "HOST": "localhost",
        "PORT": 5432,
    }
}
```

And the unit tests appears to be using the right database during the test run, appending "test" to the existing local db:

```
(Pdb) from django.db import connection
(Pdb) connection.settings_dict['NAME']
'test_mia'
```

Comment: I think it is because when you use `factory.django.DjangoModelFactory` it uses the default database `django.db.DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS` because you don't specify the test database in `Meta`. Not quite sure why inheriting from `factory.Factory` solves your problem though.

Comment: I've edited the question. Turns out that "solution" was causing other problems, so I decided against it. I'm still stumped.

Answer (score 1):

For those seeing this issue in the future, this was the problem:

```
class SignUpTokenFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = SignUpToken

    token = fake.random_number()
    user = UserFactory()
```

There was another factory elsewhere creating and assigning an instance of the User class. This should've been  `user = Subfactory(UserFactory)`